# mpi4py not letting me send and receive array with dtype = object

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have a numpy array of dtype = object that I am trying to send and receive using comm.Send() and comm.Recv, but I'm running into errors and can't seem to debug it. The array I'm trying to send consists of 2 columns: 1 column of strings and 1 column of integers.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

data_array = np.empty(100,2), dtype=object)
data_array[:,0] = var_1
data_array[:,1] = var_2

(data_array_0, data_array_1) = np.array_split(data_array, 2)
data_array_0 = np.ascontiguousarray(data_array_0, dtype = object)
data_array_1 = np.ascontiguousarray(data_array_1, dtype = object)


if rank == 0:
    comm.Send(data_array_1, dest=1)

elif rank == 1:
    data_array_1 = np.empty([data_array_row_1, data_array_col], dtype = object)
    comm.Recv(data_array_1, source=0)  # <--- the line that's causing the error
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_clean_parallel_1.py", line 156, in <module>
    comm.Recv(data_array_1, source=0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 283, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 402, in mpi4py.MPI.message_p2p_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 388, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_p2p.for_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 155, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 101, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic
KeyError: 'O'
```

I don't really understand what's causing this issue, and if there's any possible alternative that exists where I could send/receive string data using mpi4py.

Comment: What's the problem?  You don't understand why object dtype can't be used this way?  or you don't understand why the array is object dtype?

Comment: So object dtype cannot be used with comm.Send and comm.Recv? If that's the case then is there any way I can send string data using Send and Recv?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `send` and `recv` (lowercase) for numpy arrays:

As seen on https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html:

> The variants `MPI.Comm.send()`, `MPI.Comm.recv()` and `MPI.Comm.sendrecv()`
> can communicate general Python objects.